# If $f:R\to R$ is uniformly continuous so $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(\sqrt {x^2+5})-f(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Prove that if $f:R\to R$ is uniformly continuous so

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(\sqrt {x^2+5})-f(x) = 0$$

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Look at the definition of uniform continuity. Then look at $\sqrt{x^2+5} - x$.

Comment: well I wasn't sure I can just "replace" them... that seem like there's a trap

Comment: so it's done using sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+5}-x = \frac{5}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5}} = O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).\tag{1}$$
Uniform continuity gives that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|\leq \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\epsilon$. As $x$ tends to infinity, the LHS of $(1)$ becomes arbitrarily small in absolute value, hence the wanted limit is just zero.